# How to replace *( in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

My string is **Mario *(cart)** and I need to replace the *( in order to get **Mario (cart)**. I don't want to replace just the asterisk, but the asterisk followed by an open parenthesis using global in a regex.

Here the code I'm trying to fix:

```
var str = 'Mario *(cart)';
str=str.replace(/\*\(/g,'(');
```

> **CORRECTION**
>   The regex works fine, but do not work when I leave the parenthesis without a value.

I made this code to answer at [Creating dynamic formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138314/creating-dynamic-formula)

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qpsh940m/

Comment: Works for me using that same code.

Comment: This looks fine - what's the issue you're seeing?

Comment: _"Here the code I'm trying to fix"_, fix what?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

Comment: I'm writing a fiddle

Comment: _"CORRECTION ... but do not work when I leave the parenthesis without a value."_, it still works for me

Comment: Take a look at the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following http://regexr.com/ your regex is fine.

Following [javascript replace docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) you are using correctly .replace

There is nothing wrong in your code, i tested it on the javascript console (chrome) and its worked right, here is the log:

```
var str = 'Mario *(cart)';
undefined
alert(str)
undefined
var str2 = str.replace(/\*\(/g,'(');
undefined
console.log(str2)
VM650:2 Mario (cart)
undefined
```

Where are you trying to implement it?

Its dont matter where you read it, if its right and complete.

Comment: the problems remain just with empty parenthesis